# Missing iPad 4.0 Simulator

Tags: ios, ipad, xcode4, ios-simulator

I'm using Xcode version 4.0. 
When I build a iPad app which has the deployment target 3.2, Xcode schema has no iPad 4.0 Simulator.
How can I test my iPad app on iOS version 4.0 using the simulator. Is Xcode not having iPad 4.0 Simulator or should I enable it ??

Answer (score 2):

Look under `Downloads` in `Preferences`

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to add a (new) simulator

1. Click on **Simulator** icon and open simulator list.
2. At the end of list, there is an option to add new simulator "**Add Additional Simulator**". That will open **'Device & Simulator'** window.
3. Switch to **'Simulator'** tab.
4. There are three field in simulator tab.
5. Click on **'+'** icon, on left bottom corner of window.
6. Simulator Name: *Enter simulator name here*
7. Device Type: *Select **iPad** from this dropdown list*
8. OS Version: *Select OS version from this dropdown list*
9. Click on **'Create'**

A new simulator will be added in your Simulator option list.

Look at this snapshot to understand flow of above steps:
[image]

And if there is no simulator/OS version in simulator list, you're looking for,

1. Click on **Simulator** icon and open simulator list.
2. At the end of list, there is an option to add new simulator "**Download Simulator**". That will open **'Component'** window (from Xcode >> Preferences).
3. Select/click simulator from list, which you need to download.

Look at this snapshot:
[image]